# How to see if there's a post at a later date in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have two buttons in my archive page, one goes back to the previous month, the other goes forward. The problem is, if there are no posts for a certain month, it breaks the site. Is there a way to determine if a month has zero posts, and if so, determine which month next has posts so I can replace the button in the archive?

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to determine if the next or previous month has posts in the archive. If it doesn't, I'd like to provide a link to the next available month archive with posts in it.

```
<div class="btns wide"><a href="/episodes/<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($post->post_date)); ?>/<?php echo date("m", strtotime($post->post_date . "first day of last month")); ?>" class="btn outline blue prev"><i class="fas fa-podcast"></i>Episodes from <?php echo date("F Y", strtotime($post->post_date . "first day of last month")); ?></a>
    <?php
    $next_month = date("F", strtotime("first day of next month"));

    if ($next_month != date("F", strtotime($post->post_date . "first day of next month")))
    {
    ?>
    <a href="/episodes/<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($post->post_date)); ?>/<?php echo date("m", strtotime($post->post_date . "first day of next month")); ?>" class="btn outline blue next"><i class="fas fa-podcast"></i>Episodes from <?php echo date("F Y", strtotime($post->post_date . "first day of next month")); ?></a></div>
    <?php
    } else { ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code snippets which create the current buttons?  Maybe check the time archives of the default themes.

Comment: I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
<?php
   /**** start archive pagination **/
   global $post;
   $monthPaginationInfo = getMonthPaginationInfo($post);
   ?>
   <div class="btns wide <?php if($monthPaginationInfo["next"] == false || $monthPaginationInfo["prev"] == false): ?>end<?php endif; ?>">
     <?php if($monthPaginationInfo["prev"] != false): ?>
     <a href="/episodes/<?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["prev"]["year"]; ?>/<?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["prev"]["month"]; ?>/" class="btn outline blue prev"><i class="fas fa-podcast"></i> Episodes from <?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["prev"]["monthName"]; ?> <?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["prev"]["year"]; ?>
     </a>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if($monthPaginationInfo["next"] != false): ?>
     <a href="/episodes/<?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["next"]["year"]; ?>/<?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["next"]["month"]; ?>/" class="btn outline blue next"><i class="fas fa-podcast"></i> Episodes from <?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["next"]["monthName"]; ?> <?php echo $monthPaginationInfo["next"]["year"]; ?>
    </a>
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php
   /**** end archive pagination **/
```